# Unexplained Lag In Websocket Connection Using Socket.io Exactly 10 Seconds From Page Load

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

**Problem:** I have a security camera that only remotely exposes the current frame, requiring me to poll for this frame on an interval to get a video-like stream. To synchronize the frame shown to all of the clients, I am using Socket.io to stream the frames as base64 strings from the server every 500ms. The problem I am encountering is that on my desktop computer, everything works perfectly fine but on slower devices (phones and tablets) the feed would stop on a frame and wait a while (around 40-60 secs) and then a bunch of frames would rush in to try to catch up. The feed ends up with a 10ish second delay from then on.

**Steps Taken/Info/Context:**

- This occurs almost exactly 10 seconds after the pages loads.
- The socket successfully sends me a few images until the lag starts, so
  its not even the first time this code gets run.
- I am not doing anything specific at that moment so its not a blocking function.
- The images are compressed so the base64 string size does not exceed Socket.io's message size limit.
- I tried moving the socket code to a web worker so that it would be on a separate thread but the lag still exists.
- Socket.io's debug information does not show anything specific at that moment, all websocket activity simply stops, the websocket reports a `ping timeout`, it reconnects successfully and then everything works fine again.
- I tried setting some options in Socket.io based on other issues I read about like `transports: [ 'websocket' ], allowUpgrades: false` or `pingInterval: 500, pingTimeout: 60000, upgradeTimeout: 30000, timeout: 30000` and neither of these helped as well.
- All JavaScript code unrelated to websockets continues to run without issue during the lag period.
- I added this line `socket.sendBuffer = [];` to my socket connection event to see if the rush of images after the lag was somehow in this buffer but it still happened.
- Nothing was wrong with the network at the time as I can see several `fetch` requests working just fine during this lag period.

**Questions:** What is causing the lag when nothing is happening with the websocket at that moment? Why is it exactly 10 seconds AFTER the page load? If its system resources/proccessing power related, why would giving it it's own thread not help? How is there a rush of images right after the lag when Socket.io's documentation says that no emits are saved in a buffer during a disconnect?

**EDIT:** This seems to be a problem with Chrome. Firefox and Edge don't have this issue. Edge has its own issues but that's expected.

Comment: This *could* be a problem either with processing/internet speeds as well as missing browser features so I would research that if you haven't already.

Comment: is it TCP or UDP socket?

Comment: I would run profiling (Performance tab) on that device. It can give some clues..